# How do I throw an exception when I get multiple elements but I'm supposed to get only one?

Tags: javascript, linq, knex.js, fail-fast

I'm worried about this code:

```
knex('person').where('id','=', 1).then(result => {
    const person = result[0]; // the code I worry - result should contain only ONE element
});
```

If I was using C#, I would use Linq's Single, it would fail fast and throw an exception if there are more than one element in result, say the where clause is forgotten or has wrong condition.

How would I implement that in JavaScript?

Comment: Why not just [`limit`](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-limit) it?

Comment: Just `return Promise.reject("More than 1 result")` if the condition is met.

Comment: @MikeC the code would not fail if it returns more than row due to for example, a wrong where logic. if LIMIT is used, the code will silently continue even when it's receiving random data due to wrong where logic

Comment: @Hao Sure, but you could limit the results to, say, 2 so that it does not get any more data than necessary. Check `result.length > 1` and throw an error.

Comment: @MikeC Yes could use LIMIT 2 and result.length check, I'm looking for a one-liner though. `result.Single()` would cause an exception in C# if Single detected more than one element

Comment: If possible add OrderBy to your query and always select the first one.(if applicable)

Comment: @ShriramManoharan that would still cause silent errors to slip through, say the where has wrong condition. would want to make things fail fast if there is wrong implemented code

Comment: @Hao There's nothing built-in to the system to give you a one-liner + error. You could write your own function which extends that library and make it throw an error though.